# Can the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem be generalized for functions from a compact to a complete metric space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Can the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem be generalized for functions from a compact metric space to a complete metric space?

Comment: No, you need totally boundedness. $\mathbb{R}$ is a good counterexample

Comment: Yes, it can be generalized, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Generalizations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, there are generalizations, some of which can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Generalizations).